# How to build an effective top Nidalee?

Tags: league-of-legends

What is the best way to build an effective top nidalee? Also, what are some counters for nidalee so i may play her around them?

Comment: Whoever voted to close, this is not a bad question. Strategic recommendations are the bread and butter of our site.

Comment: Check out http://www.solomid.net/guides.php?g=13827 for the first part of your question

Answer (score 1):

If you go nidalee top i would see you as ad bruiser. build

boots - 3 health pot - Wriggle's Lantern - Phage - Warmog's Armor - Atma's Impaler - Trinity Force - What you need..

Answer (score -1):

Nidalee scales well with AP and in solo top she can use it to heal herself, but you might want some Mana Regen to help spam the heals more often. A little bit of health and other tank stat would help too. As for countering her, you just have to avoid her Spears and she won't be able to harass you very well.